# How to tell the robot to go to a location on the map

Tags: ros, navigation, 3d-slam, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals

This tutorial shows how to tell the robot to move forward. However, if I want to let this robot move to a certain coordinate on the map what should I do? I tried to minus the target location (hardcore it) with the current location(got from /odom) and send this to navigation stack, but it for reason unknown to me does work well.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268328/how-to-tell-the-robot-to-go-to-a-location-on-the-map/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-08-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-08**:
This would be easier to answer if you posted your attempted solution (code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [sendingSimpleGoals](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) would help, you can add your goals with certain coordiante and send the goal after one is complete

---

Originally posted by [marine0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/30508/marine0131/) with karma: 48 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0